# How does Yodlee handle an unsuccessful login

Tags: yodlee

I'm wondering what happens with auto refreshes on Yodlee's end once an account fails to authenticate the user's credentials?

Does the daily refresh still take place, or is this process paused until the credentials are updated?

I guess what I want to know is if our user changes their bank credentials, and not the credentials stored in Yodlee, will they eventually be locked out from Yodlee continuing to attempt to login?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Let us say a consumer changed his/her bank credentials at the bank website while Yodlee system credentials are not updated. Yodlee will try to refresh the consumer's account at scheduled time and it will fail with LOGIN_EXCEPTION(error code- 402) which means credentials are not valid.

Once, Yodlee system gets this error code it will refrain from doing any more retries(which may result into Account Locked or some other issues) and will wait for consumer to update the credentials into Yodlee system.